# Will Scalar Functions not work with Aggregate queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have defined an user defined scalar function, to convert time to second:

```
Create function [dbo].[TIME_TO_SEC](@inputTime time)
returns INT
As
Begin 
    DECLARE @secDiff INT = datediff(second, '00:00:00', @inputTime)
    return @secDiff;
end
```

Above function works fine but when I try to invoke this inside aggregate function say, 'SUM'

```
SELECT emp.EmpId
    ,sum(dbo.TIME_TO_SEC(au.BirthDateTime)) AS EmployeeBirthDay
FROM Employee emp
```

I get below error:

> Column 'Employee .EmpId' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

P.S. Please note I have tried to replicate MySQL `TIME_TO_SEC` functionality in above user-defined function.

Comment: You are missing `Group By emp.EmpId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the EmpId in the Group By clause:

```
SELECT emp.EmpId
    ,sum(dbo.TIME_TO_SEC(au.BirthDateTime)) AS EmployeeBirthDay
FROM Employee emp
GROUP BY emp.EmpID
```

Answer (score 0):

add Group By:

```
SELECT emp.EmpId
    ,sum(dbo.TIME_TO_SEC(au.BirthDateTime)) AS EmployeeBirthDay
FROM Employee emp
GROUP BY Emp.EmpID
```